# FQL Multiquery always fails (querys work as single query)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to fetch the users news stream and get the names of the profiles from the actor ids of the news stream posts.

This is the query I use

```
NSString *fqlString = @"{"
@"'query0':'SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 5',"
@"'query1':'SELECT id, name, pic_square FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query0)',"
@"}";
```

This returns an OAuth Exception which says: `"(#601) Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0."`

In fact it doesn't make sense because query0 and query1 are working both as single query.

Can anybody help me with that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

1. A synthax error: `type='newsfeed'` must be `type="newsfeed"`, because your query already starts after an apostrophe `'`.
2. `uid2` can't be found into `#query0`, because the field `uid2` does not exist into the `stream` table. You most probably need the `actor_id` instead.

Here is your FQL query corrected:

```
{
 'query0':'SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type="newsfeed") AND is_hidden = 0 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 5',
 'query1':'SELECT id, name, pic_square FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #query0)'
}
```

[Try it here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=%7B%0A%20%27query0%27%3a%27SELECT%20post_id,%20actor_id,%20message,%20created_time%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20filter_key%20in%20%28SELECT%20filter_key%20FROM%20stream_filter%20WHERE%20uid=me%28%29%20AND%20type=%22newsfeed%22%29%20AND%20is_hidden%20=%200%20ORDER%20BY%20created_time%20DESC%20LIMIT%205%27,%0A%20%27query1%27%3a%27SELECT%20id,%20name,%20pic_square%20FROM%20profile%20WHERE%20id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20actor_id%20FROM%20#query0%29%27%0A%7D)